# Proper type of object of constructors

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following object:

```
export const PageConstructors: {[index: string]: any} = {
    [PageName.MAIN] : MainPage,
    [PageName.SCOREBOARD] : ScoreboardPage,
};
```

MainPage and ScoreboardPage are both children of Page. I want to replace the `any` with the correct type. However I am stumped in finding the right typescript syntax. I've tried various combinations of `new<T extends Page>() => T` without luck. Is this possible?

Comment: Did not work. Here is a playground test: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20constructors%3A%20%7B%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20new%20%3CT%20extends%20Parent%3E()%20%3D%3E%20T%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20Child%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor itself is not generic. Your constructor signature can return the base class instead.

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {

    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();        
    }
}


const constructors: { [index: string]: new () => Parent } = {
    test: Child,
}
```

If the constructor can take arguments you can take a rest of `any` or `unknown`

```
const constructors: { [index: string]: new (...a:unknown[]) => Parent } = {
    test: Child,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the arguments, that caused the error.